# Using Open, Write and Close System Calls in C

Tags: c

I'm having problems with very basic use of Open, Write and Close system calls in C, the following code is compiling but showing 0 bytes written to the file and no content being output into the file. What am I doing wrong?!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t numWritten;

    if(fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND) == - 1)
        printf("There has been an error opening the file\n");
    else
    {
        if(numWritten = write(fd, "Test Text\n", 10) == -1)
            printf("There has been an error writing to the file!\n");
        else
            printf("You have written %ld bytes\n", (long)numWritten);
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also if `open` failed the file descriptor is invalid, so you shouldn't try to `close` it (move `close` into the `else` block).

Comment: What is the boolean result of 'open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND) == - 1' likely to be, and why are you assigning it to an fd?

Comment: "If the file does not exist, create it. If the O_CREAT option is used, then you must include the third parameter." See http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Ah and naturally you have the parentheses missing in num_written too

Comment: @RichardChambers yes it is. If there are *more* duplicates, point them out and I will add them too

Comment: I have no idea how this code can behave as described:(

Comment: @MartinJames `open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND) == - 1` will evaluate to `0`. So the string is written to standard *input* which is opened to terminal. Therefore the string is displayed there, because even `stdin` is opened in read mode.

Comment: Owait - the file opens OK, the compare is false and so fd gets loaded with 0, so that the write is to stdin.. :(

Comment: yes. OP just misses two sets of parentheses and the mode argument, for example `0644`.

Comment: To answer the "What am I doing wrong?!" part,
Add a parenthesis pair in your if-write line and everything works fine.
from:
  if(numWritten = write(fd, "Test Text\n", 10) == -1)
to:
  if( (numWritten = write(fd, "Test Text\n", 10)) == -1)